# how to fetch 1st url from string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to fetch 1st url from given string and display in

```
@urls.each do |url_list|
  url_list.url
end

"http://www.med.nagoya-u.ac.jp/hospital/1388/1391/s_tounyoubyounaibunpitsunaika.html\nhttp://www.med.nagoya-u.ac.jp/medical/6391/6393/tounyoubyounaibunpitsunaikagaku.html\nhttp://www.med.nagoya-u.ac.jp/endodm/greeting/index.html\nhttp://www.med.nagoya-u.ac.jp/naika/outline/tounyou-naibunpitsu.html\nhttp://www.med.nagoya-u.ac.jp/hospital/dbps_data/_material_/nu_hospital/gairai_tantou/201501_tantoui.pdf\nhttp://www.med.nagoya-u.ac.jp/hospital/1388/1389/eiyoukanribu.html"
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear in your question if the example string is stored in `@urls`, `url_list` or `url_list .url` and if you only want to extract and show the first URL or all (with `each`).

Comment: i have columns url where in some rows url column has only single url whereas some rows consists more than one url from that rows i have to fetch first url

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your string is separated by newlines (`\n`). That means to only fetch the first URL from that string you can do this:

```
original_string.split("\n").first
```